# checkboxradio() of jquery is not working

Tags: jquery

`checkboxradio()` of jQuery is not working. I tried a lot, but radio button are being appeared as simple html radio button.

```js
$("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio();
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p style="width:50%;margin-left:25%">Add User</p>

<div id="tab">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tab-1">

    <table id=" tab1_table" class="right">

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="username">UserName</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="password">Enter Password</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="password">Confirm Password</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" id="confirmpassword" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="tab-2">

    <table id="tab2_table">

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber" value="">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="aboutyou">Date Of Birth</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Gender :</label>
        </td>

        <td>
          <label for="radio-1">Male</label>
          <input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-1">
        </td>
        <td>
          <label for="radio-2">Female</label>
          <input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-2">
        </td>
        <td>
          <label for="radio-3">Other</label>
          <input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-3">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="tab-3">
    <table id="tab3_table">
      <tr>
        <td>Country:</td>
        <td>
          <select class="countryDropDown">
            <option value="">--Select Country--</option>
            <option value="INDIA">India</option>
            <option value="UK">UK</option>
            <option value="USA">USA</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>State:</td>
        <td>
          <select class="stateDropDown">
            <option value="">--Select State--</option>

          </select>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="aboutyou">About You</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="aboutyou" id="resizable_aboutyou" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <center>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
          </center>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the jquery ui version 1.12 to work

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

**working code:**

```js
$("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio();
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p style="width:50%;margin-left:25%">Add User</p>

<div id="tab">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tab-1">

    <table id=" tab1_table" class="right">

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="username">UserName</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="password">Enter Password</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="password">Confirm Password</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" id="confirmpassword" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="tab-2">

    <table id="tab2_table">

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber" value="">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="aboutyou">Date Of Birth</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Gender :</label>
        </td>

        <td>
          <label for="radio-1">Male</label>
          <input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-1">
        </td>
        <td>
          <label for="radio-2">Female</label>
          <input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-2">
        </td>
        <td>
          <label for="radio-3">Other</label>
          <input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-3">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="tab-3">
    <table id="tab3_table">
      <tr>
        <td>Country:</td>
        <td>
          <select class="countryDropDown">
            <option value="">--Select Country--</option>
            <option value="INDIA">India</option>
            <option value="UK">UK</option>
            <option value="USA">USA</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>State:</td>
        <td>
          <select class="stateDropDown">
            <option value="">--Select State--</option>

          </select>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="aboutyou">About You</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="aboutyou" id="resizable_aboutyou" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <center>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
          </center>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its working now, but now the sign of radio button is missing, only options like male , female are visible. Can you please say , how it will show the sign of radio button as well?

Comment: welcome. please check now...updated!!!. Also, if you find this answer helpful, pl accept and upvote.

Comment: @Sarbani : pl accept the answer and upvote it. If you don't know ,let me know, i can help you.

Comment: This is my first post in stack overflow and my rating is still below 15. So , my voting is not being shown as per stackover flow rule.

Comment: Tried this solution 1 year later: Using jQuery 1.12.4 and jqueryUI 1.12.1: Using the jQuery selector for classes or IDs it works fine. Using the selector $("input").checkboxradio() or $("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio() simply does not work.